# css not linked photo contest wordpress plugin

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have download the plugin in the title to manage a photo contest. I want to customize the menu but if I modified the .css file it doesn't change.
This is the link to the page:
https://www.good-look.it/contest/
I modified the file in path wp-content/themes/blankslate/css/public.css
I search in whitch .php the stylesheet is linked but i can't find it.
In the plugin page demo (http://codecanyon.net/item/photo-contest-wordpress-plugin/full_screen_preview/8320636) menu is completely different so I think there is something wrong with my wordpress or with my theme. Blankslate is a basic theme that give you basic files to start write a theme. 
Suggestions?

Comment: A wordpress theme should always be named theme.css (unless you tell wordpress its different via functions.php), else wordpress wont read it. If it is an external css, you ll have to check if wordpress loads it in via functions.php. Also your menu is stated as an article, not really a menu (in the good-look contest page). Also your look-good is loaded with 3 CSS files, good-look, reset and struttara. Which one you require? If you wanna add a css, you ll have to go through the functions.php

Comment: but the rest of the site work perfectly!

Comment: you wanna add it as an external stylesheet? You ll need to dive into the functions.php to tell there is another stylesheet. `wp_enqueue_style` is the command you looking for.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand exactly what I have to do.. Can you be more specific?

Comment: http://www.paulund.co.uk/add-stylesheets-to-wordpress-correctly Try this first. I think you just have a problem with not calling your css correctly.